# Why isn't SoundFile.play not working processing 4

Tags: java, audio, processing

So I'm trying to play a simple sound file and it's not working. The specific code is

```
  if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
    file = new SoundFile(this, "track1.wav");
    file.play();
  }
  if(key == 't' || key == 'T') {
    file = new SoundFile(this, "track2.wav");
    file.play();
  }
  if(key == 'y' || key == 'Y') {
    file = new SoundFile(this, "track3.wav");
    file.play();
  }
```

It gives me this error

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:484)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:115)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine.read(byte[], int, int)" because "this.line" is null
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.RuntimeException: AudioInput stop attempted when no line created.
    at com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice$JavaSoundInputStream.stop(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsyn.engine.SynthesisEngine$EngineThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try saving the wav file as PCM *unsigned* (44100 Hz, 16 bit). There are multiple ways of doing this. AFAIK, Audacity (which is free and opensource) can help with this)

Comment: It has to do with the data format of your WAV files. Audio editors such as Audacity can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to add this sound files under res folder.
in my project, I created folder named "raw" under "res folde" with these files in it, sound.mp3
and for playing it, i used this

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SCREEN_NAME.this,R.track1);
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
```

edit:
and i created this variable

```
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```